# How to find last (final) URL after series of redirects via shortened URL from PHP

Tags: php, php-curl

I built a custom plugin for WordPress that people can post without having to register / login, but just double confirming the password. It has been working well, spam free, but someone started posting spammy links.

I wrote a plugin to detect the pattern based on IP address then block the IP and delete all posts for those who got blocked. However, I think this spammer is using a tool that spoofs or switches IP address and started posting from a different IP address. One thing in common I found is that the links go to the same URL after series of redirects.

I've tried the following functions to trace the destination, but no luck.

```
myfunction( $url ){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
  curl_exec($ch);
  $lastUrl = curl_getinfo($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $lastUrl;
}
```

I've also tried getting the header information from the link, but no luck.

So, I tried many online tool that grabs the final URL from the link, and none of them worked.

The URL shortener service this spammer uses is http://urnic.com/

I don't think it is doing a JavaScript redirect as it worked with JS turned off from my Chrome.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it. (Here's a good [Markdown Tutorial](https://commonmark.org/help/) as well).

Comment: "no luck" means what exactly? What results _did_ you get? If there is a series of redirects are you attempting to follow them and get to the final one? It's not really clear from your code.

Comment: Have you tried a captcha approach?

Comment: @JohnConde Thank you for the guide. I spent some time trying to use the "code" option in the editor, but it didn't work well. I'll refer to the guide you provided.

Comment: @ADyson Basically, the returned URL is the source URL passed to the function. So, it is not able to detect where the redirect goes.

Comment: @apokryfos We had to leave out the captcha approach due to the usability reasons. It is being used so some of the minority community website and people complain about hard to use captcha.

Answer (score 0):

you can use curl's CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION + CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL to find the final address, provided that the redirects you speak of are HTTP-redirects (eg HTTP 3xx `300 Multiple Choices` or `301 Moved Permanently` or `302 Found` or `307 Temporary Redirect` or some such),

```
function get_final_url(string $redirect_url):string{
$ch=curl_init($redirect_url);
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=>1,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING=>'',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>'many_websites_block_UAless_requests',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1, // ideally we should use CURLOPT_NOBODY but some websites respond differently to HEAD requests, so using GET requests is the safest option =/ (also if you're worried about ram usage, you should set CURLOPT_OUTFILE to /dev/null or enable CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION)
));
curl_exec($ch);
$ret=curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
curl_close($ch);
return $ret;
}
```

(**ps! untested, might be a typo or something, but that should work in theory.**)

as i mentioned in a code-comment, the function can be optimized to use less ram if you're worried about huge responses (CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER put the entire response in-ram, can be fixed by using an empty CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION)

anyhow, that should return the final url.

Comment: It still doesn't see the destination url. It returns the shortened url instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can make with preg_match and catch location url. its working for me perfectly.

```
    $curlhandle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'googlebot');
    curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $final = curl_exec($curlhandle);
    if (preg_match('~Location: (.*)~i', $final, $lasturl)) {
       $loc = trim($lasturl[1]);
       echo $loc;
    } else {
       echo "Dont have redirect url...";
    }
```

This will behavior like googlebot and will show you redirected url.

only add `curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'googlebot');` this code.

Comment: It still doesn't find the destination url. The URL I am testing is http://urnic.com/75D which should return https://www.yahoo.com

Comment: no need to use regex here, you can just ask curl with `curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);`

Comment: @Rosean your url dont have redirect normally. its working with javascript redirect after page load. here check https://prnt.sc/t1vpml

Comment: Ok i found your problem. Only add useragent googlebot and you will see redirect url.